# svg d3 circular control

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am trying to make a control in which radial lines are sticking outside of a circle.  the length of each line sticking out depends on data value. In short we can see it as a bar chart with circular axis.

Is there anything (or an example) in d3 that already exists for this.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Tintin...there are variations on the theme, like [this one](http://prcweb.co.uk/radialbarchart/)...from Cap. Haddock :)

Comment: However, there should be caution with these area-based radial charts since they tend to inflate the true distance between values. So, lines radiating from the center is probably more desirable. Some further googling may yield more fruits.

Comment: Hi Fern, I do NOT want an area based polar chart.  All I want is "Sun" like control where the length of rays (lines coming out of circle) correspond to the data value.  What you have shown are area based (arc based) charts.  What I am looking is probably conceptually different...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such examples, but here's a [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/t7kYT/). The idea is to create the bars as usual and then rotate them around the center point:

```
svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter()
  .append("rect")
  .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return scale(d); })
  .attr("width", 20)
  .attr("y", r)
  .attr("x", -10)
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "rotate(" + (360/data.length * i - 180) + ")";
  });
```